# Error compiling after adding a font as a resource file to the Delphi project

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Delphi Rio, I would like to distribute a font by embedding it into the application executable.  But I've got errors, as shown below, when compiling the application.

I just added a font using `Project->Resources and Images` dialog, without doing anything else at all.

[image]

Please guide how to fix the error.

Project1Resource.rc:

```
1 FONT "Kanit-Black.ttf"
```

Project1.dpr:

```pascal
program Project1;

{$R *.dres}

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Compiler Output:

```
Build started 07/18/2020 01:14:16 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "C:\Users\John\Desktop\foo\Project1.dproj" (Build target(s)):
Target BuildVersionResource:
    c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\cgrc.exe -c65001 Project1.vrc -foProject1.res 
    CodeGear Resource Compiler/Binder
    Version 1.2.2 Copyright (c) 2008-2012 Embarcadero Technologies Inc.
    
    Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
    
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    
    
    Deleting file "Project1.vrc".
    Deleting file "Project1.$manifest".
Target BuildProjectResourceFile:
    c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\cgrc.exe -c65001 Project1Resource.rc -foProject1.dres 
    CodeGear Resource Compiler/Binder
    Version 1.2.2 Copyright (c) 2008-2012 Embarcadero Technologies Inc.
    
    Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
    
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    
    
    
    RC : fatal error RW1023: I/O error seeking in file
    c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1004,5): error MSB6006: "brcc32" exited with code 1.
Done building target "BuildProjectResourceFile" in project "Project1.dproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "Project1.dproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1004,5): error MSB6006: "brcc32" exited with code 1.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.18
```

Comment: Have you attempted to *build* the application (Shift+F9)?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I did but, I have got the same error, thanks.

Comment: I've never used the IDE's "Images and Resources" dialog. Do you have the same issue if you move the resource to a separate `.rc` file that the IDE does not manage, and then manually compile it into a `.res` file, and then link the `.res` file into the project using an explicit `{$R 'myfont.res'}` directive in your code? Or better, use `{$R 'myfont.res' 'myfont.rc'}` and let the compiler handle the compiling and linking of the `.rc` file for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I created `Fonts.rc` manually using `1 FONT "Resources\\Kanit-Regular.ttf"` but I got an error `Invalid font format` when compiling with `brcc32.exe`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Alternatively with `1 ANYOL1 "Resources\\Kanit-Regular.ttf"` has no complains from `brcc32.exe` but after adding `{$R 'Fonts.res' 'Fonts.rc'}` to the `Project1.dpr` I got error from `TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, '1', Pchar('ANYOL1'));` saying that `Resource 1 not found` please guide, what I did wrong? I also still don't know what `ANYOL1` is, so I'm not sure what is incorrect in this approach.
P.S I still keep the default coding `{$R *.res}` in my `Project1.dpr`

Comment: Based on the fact that you are getting `Invalid font format` error when trying to manually add your font to `.rc` file it is possible that the font file may actually not be in correct format or it is damaged. Any way I went and found this font file on creators [github](https://github.com/cadsondemak/kanit) page and downloaded the `ttf` version of it to my computer. Then I was able to add it to a test project using `Resources and images` dialog and compile my test project just fine. So I recommend you download the font file again and try adding the new one to your application.

Comment: @Artisan the resource TYPE is a user-defined string, it can be anything you want, though there are [various types that are predefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-types), like `FONT`, `RCDATA`, etc. Try using `RCDATA` if `FONT` is not working. As for the resource ID, you defined a *numeric* ID in the `.rc` file but then tried to load the resource using a *string* ID. That is why the resource could not be found. Pass the ID as an integer not a string: `TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 1, RT_RCDATA) `

Comment: Compiling resource with BRCC32 always fails for that exact same font that I can add and compile via `resources and images`. Also I can compile that resource file using Visual Studio `rc.exe` and use it with delphi with no issue! \facepalm\